# Bootstrap Tabs with Glyphicons

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Wondering if someone could help...

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified active">
        <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Tab 1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="active current"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Tab 3  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have simple coding here using Bootstrap for a few tabs.

On an active state, I'm looking for the glyphicon to rotate 90 degrees for a nice transition. I've seen quite a few variations, but looking for the best way for nav-pills.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Does something like this do the trick? I'm assuming you only need to rotate the span. This should do that for you whenever the li has class 'active'

```
li.active span{transform: rotate(90deg);}
```

Comment: add some css3 transition to the li so it makes it smooth

Comment: Worked a treat! Added some css transition effects too! Thanks! :)